# Bandwidth saturation due to Googlebot search for spam pages

Tags: googlebot, spam, 404, bandwidth

I recently had to update the hosting plan of a WordPress site I run due to bandwidth excess, which was already quite high. 
I've installed a security plugin that keeps log of 404 errors. From here I see a large amount of accesses to spam pages from an IP that results being from a Googlebot.
I've disallowed all bots to crawl my pages and that seems to stop those bulk access to non existing pages. Of course this is a temporary solution to avoid that my site is being blocked. How can I stop Googlebot from trying to access only those pages?

Answer (score 1):

If the URLs they are requesting follow some patterns, I think it *is* a good idea to block those pages. Based on your comment above, in your robots.txt you could add:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /data/
```

That will work as long as you don't have any real URLs beginning with `data`.

The second thing you may want to do is decrease Google's crawl rate. You can do this in Google Webmaster Tools.

There is also a `Crawl-delay` setting in robots.txt - Google ignores this but it is useful for other search engines. I'd advise not setting it higher than 4.

Comment: Yes, use Webmaster tools. Add your site to Google Webmaster Tools and set your preferred crawl rate, please see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

404 errors are a part of business. They can come from poorly made links on other sites, current link on your own site, or from pages that have been removed without a current existing link.

You do not want to block the search engines from accessing pages that do not exist unless you do not want to be in the search engine at all.

If you are blocking Google, for example, using a robots.txt file, you will be delisted. You are saying to Google, *I do not want what you are offering.*

You do want to allow 404 errors to occur. How else can Google know these pages are gone? You can replace a 404 error with a 410 which would shorten the process. A 404 means temporarily gone while a 410 means gone. Google will try and access pages that return a 404 error for a period of time for a certain number of accesses before it determines the page is truly gone. If you return a 410 error, Google will stop trying to access the page after one access. But keep in mind that any search engine may try again if they find a link on another site just in case.

Comment: I know that blocking googlebot is not a good idea, but it's a temporary solution to avoid bandwidth saturation. Googlebot is trying to access pages that NEVER existed on my site (spam pages due to hacking of site, i.e.  
data/annonce-rencontre-homme-serieux-poissy-27062dd-1.html) in means of one per minute, thus quickly saturating my bandwidth. What I wanted to know is how to stop googlebot from pointing to these spam pages...

Comment: @RobertoPravisani By letting Google do its work. Otherwise, it will not stop. These links are out there and no matter what you do, Google will chase them down thinking they are valid pages. The only way for Google to know they are invalid is to attempt to fetch them. If you block Google, you are causing more damage than if you just let it go. If one spam access per minute is eating your bandwidth, I wonder how little bandwidth you have??